# Potential methods for segmenting and grouping points from lines represented by 3d point cloud

Tags: geometry, curve-fitting, computational-geometry, point-clouds, curve

Iinked image summarizes what I want to solve: [Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn0gI.png)

From a combination of unordered points in 3D space, I would like to identify intersection- and end- points, and groups points that form 3D curves.

At the moment, I assume that distance between two neighboring points is always the same.

For identifying the intersection- and end- points, I tried to use KNN algorithm to identify how many neighboring points exist for each point sample (e.g., 1 neighboring point = end-point & >2 neighboring points = intersection points). However, this method does not work properly when branched curves are close to each other.

For grouping points, I checked out data clustering and curve fitting while I was not able to find any curve fitting algorithm that works for 3D data and branched curves. Popular clustering algorithms like K-means and DBSCAN also do not work for my application. I know that there is algorithms called "skeletonization", but I'm not sure whether it is a good candidate for my specific application....

I would appreciate it if somebody could share their insights and information.

Comment: Starting from two adjacent points(for example, a end-point and its only neighbor), you can estimate the position of the next point.
When you find a point located enoughly near from the estimation, you can assume as "their 3 points are continuous : part of line or curve". Then from 3 points, finding 4th...
Points belong to multiple lines/curves will be intersection points.

Comment: (The next point location estimation may become extrapolation with local curve fitting.)